# Adding a Message-ID using Amazon SES

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to track messages which have been sent through work and coding an automatic bounce handler.  Using a tutorial, I found the following are headers for mail.

How do I add the header information to the below, which will include list unsubscription links and also the X-Message-ID?

```
$msg = array();
$msg['Source'] = "Robert Ferris <info@...>";
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = "Harry <harry@...>";

$msg['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = "Text only subject";
$msg['Message']['Subject']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";

$msg['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] ="Text data of email";
$msg['Message']['Body']['Text']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";
$msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] ="<br><strong>HTML Data of email<strong /><br />";
$msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";
```